# Invocation of Delegates Issue

Tags: c#

Like I told you in my previous question I am learning about delegates or better said I am trying to answer all my question I have about those bad boys.

MSDN Docs somehow do not really help me much. They couldn't really answer me following issue:

I have this code:

```
public delegate void Del(string message);
```

Now what you told me yesterday is that somehow compiler creates a delegate from that line with the type Del.

You also told me yesterday that every delegate inherits from `Delegate` (with cap letter) class.

So far so good but now my question is I can do following `Del d = DoSomething; d();` but why can't I do the same with `Delegate`?.

I cannot do something like this `Delegate e = d; e()`. There is only DynamicInvoke method but no direct invocation.

What is that `Delegate` (with cap letter) good for anyway if everybody suggests somehow to stay away from it?

I wish you guys not to link me to some other already existing answer. I would appreciate if somebody could take 5 min time to discuss with me here about this if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each delegate has a strong **signature**: both return types and argument types are required to be specified. The base `Delegate` class is here to materialize any delegate, but not with purpose to be called directly.

It's the same as the `Enum` class. It's a base class to help dealing with enums.

Comment: Ok I didn't see all that like you. Thanks. But Enums have no DynamicInvoke method do they? What I dont get is why I need that DynamicInvoke? I assign an Action to Delegate and all of a suddent I need DynamicInvoke which uses reflactoring in background to run the method. Why when I already know the method/delegate since I assigned  the Action to Delegate in first place.

Comment: @devhedgehog I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but it's probably because the signature needs to match at compile-time, not just at runtime

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because when you declare a `delegate` `Del` the compiler creates a class `Del` that sub-classes `Delegate` which is an abstract class. So

```
    Del d = DoSomething;
```

is actually a shortcut for

```
    Del d = new Del(DoSomething);
```

you can't do the same with `Delegate` because it is an abstract class, so

```
    Delegate e = new Delegate(d);
```

is illegal.

Comment: Hi Ned I was talking about invocation. You seem to be talking about initialization. Good point though. Yes Delegate class is an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, per your code the snippet

```
Del d = DoSomething; 
d();
```

will fail to compile, with a invalid signature error, as the call does not match the signature (you will need something like `d("Hello world")` to make it work. Also using a return value of `d` will yield a compile time error (e.g. `var result = d("");`), because the compiler knows that `Del` delegates have a void return.

When using the same thing via a `Delegate` instance, all that can be known about the value is that is invokable, and the return type and the parameters (in number or in type) are unknown. The system enables you to invoke the delegate indirectly, via `DynamicInvoke`, dynamic here meaning that any resolution and any errors will not be known until execution time.